# BigBlueButton Checksum Bypass?

Tags: interceptor, burp, bigbluebutton

**There this VC site which uses the BBB Api and sends over variables and checksum to BBB to join a conversation. I wanted to know how I could change the fullName property without alerting the checksum.**

**I've tried using Burp Suite to pause redirection to API and then switch fullName with "Test101" and then forward, but then it results in Checksum failed, which is expected.**

**How do I (only) change my name without the checksum failed error? Ideas?**

Comment: this is not possible with out a new checksum, the checksum is basically for the full query string and other parameters so if you change the query string you need to create a new checksum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to do so. I have tried a lot and couldn't make it work. You are supposed to generate a checksum exactly based on the complete URL; any minor change in the URL, would cause Checksum failure.